# Bootstrap text fields not selectable on mobile browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-safari

On my website http://createabundance.ca, inside the payment form that is shown when any of the orange buttons are clicked, the text fields are not selectable on mobile safari or chrome, but work without issue on desktop safari, and chrome.

**Screenshot:** http://d.pr/i/nrBu

Any ideas as to what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

You have form fields like this

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group required">
        <input name="email" class="form-control" size="4" placeholder="邮件地址" type="email">
    </div>
</div>
```

remove `col-xs-12` from `<div class="col-xs-12 form-group required">` and put it in separate div `<div class="col-xs-12">` like below

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group required">
            <input name="name" class="form-control" size="4" placeholder="姓名" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it will fix the problem when form opens in mobile

sidenote: `class="form-row"` has no css property so totally remove this `<div class="form-row">` because it severing no purpose

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <input name="name" class="form-control" size="4" placeholder="姓名" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

but if you want to use `<div class="form-row">` then

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group required">
            <input name="name" class="form-control" size="4" placeholder="姓名" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```